# Multiple mat-table with MatSort within the same component

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have 2 material 2 tables in the same component with sorting. I cannot find a way to assign the MatSort directive to its own table. I'm only able to use MatSort on the first table and the second table doesn't recognize there is a MatSort on it. Does anyone know how to configure two tables with sorting in the same component?

I've tried defining the ViewChild with different names, but it didn't work.

```
@ViewChild('hBSort') hBSort: MatSort;
@ViewChild('sBSort') sBSort: MatSort;


this.hBSource = new HBDataSource(this.hBDatabase, this.hBPaginator, 
this.hBSort);
this.sBSource = new SBDataSource(this.sBDatabase, this.sBPaginator, 
this.sBSort);

Table 1
const displayDataChanges = [
   this.hBPaginator.page,
   this.hBSort.sortChange,
   this._filterChange
];

Table 2
const displayDataChanges = [
   this.sBPaginator.page,
   this.sBSort.sortChange,
   this._filterChange
];

Table 1
<mat-table #hBtable [dataSource]="hBSource" matSort style="min-width: 
740px;">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="domain">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> {{'list.domain' | translate}} </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.domain}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="general">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> {{'list.general' | translate}} </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.general.gNum}} ({{row.general.gPct | number: '1.1-2'}}%) </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="hBColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: hBColumns;"></mat-row>
 </mat-table>


Table 2
<mat-table #sBSort [dataSource]="sBSource" matSort style="min-width: 1200px;">
      <ng-container matColumnDef="domain">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> {{'list.domain' | translate}} </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.domain}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="general">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> {{'list.general' | translate}} </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.general.gNum}} ({{row.general.gPct | number: '1.1-2'}}%) </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="sBColumns"></mat-header-row>
      <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: sBColumns;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The fix to this is that after you define your ViewChild reference in the DOM your need to make sure to add the ="matSort" after it.

Steps:

1. Set up MatSort instances in your component and define them in your DataSource dependencies like so:

   ```
   @ViewChild('hBSort') hBSort: MatSort;
   @ViewChild('sBSort') sBSort: MatSort;

   this.hBSource = new HBDataSource(this.hBDatabase, this.hBPaginator, 
   this.hBSort);
   this.sBSource = new SBDataSource(this.sBDatabase, this.sBPaginator, 
   this.sBSort);
   ```
2. Define ViewChild References in the DOM and set them equal to matSort (Note: matSort attribute is on the mat-table tag):

   ```
   Table 1
   <mat-table #hBSort="matSort" [dataSource]="hBSource" matSort 
     style="min-width: 740px;">
               ***Table Rows and pagination***
   </mat-table>

   Table 2
   <mat-table #sBSort="matSort" [dataSource]="sBSource" matSort 
     style="min-width: 1200px;">
               ***Table Rows and pagination***
   </mat-table>
   ```

Comment: Also, if the child is hidden on startup, you may need other tricks, see https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/10205

Comment: If the tables are hidden using *ngIf, then yes because the ViewChild reference doesn't exist in the DOM. If the tables are hidden using [hidden], then it should work without any issues.

Comment: I do not know why, I tried a different answers that look just the same, and this was that work for me. Thanks. PS> I am using angular 8

Answer (score 35):

In Angular 7 to 16 you need `both` `matSort` and the reference `#sorter1="matSort"`:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="ds1" matSort #sorter1="matSort">
</table>
<table mat-table [dataSource]="ds2" matSort #sorter2="matSort">
</table>
```

Then

```
@ViewChild('sorter1') sorter1: MatSort;
@ViewChild('sorter2') sorter2: MatSort;


ngOnInit() {
this.ds1.sort = this.sorter1;
this.ds2.sort = this.sorter2;
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me with Angular 9 too. Thanks.

Comment: Works at angular 10 also.

Comment: woks as expected :)

Comment: well explained and works with angular 12.

Comment: Works at angular 16 also

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend to create a common component for table which can be used at multiple places in application. As component will create the separate instance of it, mat table did't conflicts there functionality.

In that case you don't need to repeat the code for 2 tables. Below is Table common component you can implement.

Home.component.ts

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  public data1: any[];
  public data2: any[];
  constructor() {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
   this.data1 = [
    {domain: 'Hello1', gNum: 1, gPct: 'table-data1'},
    {domain: 'Hello2', gNum: 2, gPct: 'table-data2'},
    {domain: 'Hello3', gNum: 3, gPct: 'table-data3'},
    {domain: 'Hello4', gNum: 4, gPct: 'table-data4'},
    {domain: 'Hello5', gNum: 5, gPct: 'table-data5'},
    {domain: 'Hello6', gNum: 6, gPct: 'table-data6'},
    {domain: 'Hello7', gNum: 7, gPct: 'table-data7'},
   ];
   this.data2 = [
    {domain: 'Hello1', gNum: 1, gPct: 'table-data1'},
    {domain: 'Hello2', gNum: 2, gPct: 'table-data2'},
    {domain: 'Hello3', gNum: 3, gPct: 'table-data3'},
    {domain: 'Hello4', gNum: 4, gPct: 'table-data4'},
    {domain: 'Hello5', gNum: 5, gPct: 'table-data5'},
    {domain: 'Hello6', gNum: 6, gPct: 'table-data6'},
    {domain: 'Hello7', gNum: 7, gPct: 'table-data7'},
   ]
  }
}
```

Home.component.html

```
 <app-table-component [data]='data1'></app-table-component>
 <app-table-component [data]='data2'></app-table-component>
```

Table.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-table-component',
  templateUrl: 'table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['table.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})

export class TableComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  @Input() data: any[];
  public displayedColumns = ['domain', 'gNum', 'gPct'];
  public dataSource: MatTableDataSource<any>;

  constructor() {
  }

  public ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.data);
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
   });
  }

  public ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(changes.data.currentValue);
  }

}
```

Table.component.html

```
   <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort  matSortDisableClear matSortDirection="asc">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="domain">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Domain </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.domain}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

 <ng-container matColumnDef="gNum">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>G Number </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.gNum}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="gPct">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Global Pct </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.gPct}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row  *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;">
  </mat-row>
</mat-table>

<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"></mat-paginator>
```

Comment: I agree using a component is always better. In my case the data columns for each table were very different, so for these purposes I didn't make a component that each table could share. Although, I could make a component that has dynamic columns and data classes. Thanks for another point of view!

Answer (score 6):

Here is an Angular 6 working solution:

```
import { MatSort, MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';
```

...

```
@ViewChild('sortCol1') sortCol1: MatSort;
@ViewChild('sortCol2') sortCol2: MatSort;
```

...

Data source 1:

```
this.dataSource1 = new MatTableDataSource(this.dataSource1);
this.dataSource1.sort = this.sortCol1;
```

Data source 2:

```
this.dataSource2 = new MatTableDataSource(this.dataSource2);
this.dataSource2.sort = this.sortCol2;
```

...

Table 1 (View):

```
<table mat-table #sortCol1="matSort" [dataSource]="dataSource1" matSort matSortActive="ID" matSortDirection="asc">
...
</table>
```

Table 2 (View):

```
<table mat-table #sortCol2="matSort" [dataSource]="dataSource2" matSort matSortActive="ID" matSortDirection="asc">
...
</table>
```

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:**

I believe you need:

```
@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
```

above your:

```
@ViewChild('hBSort') hBSort: MatSort;
@ViewChild('sBSort') sBSort: MatSort;
```

Then:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.hBSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.sBSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
```

Assuming that your HBDataSource and SBDataSource both export MatTableDataSource();

I'm referencing these sources:

https://material.angular.io/components/sort/overview
https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/demo-app/table/table-demo.ts

Comment: Wouldn't that just create another reference to a sort directive, because @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort; just references the mat-table with the matSort attribute on it. I tried it, but it didn't work :(

Comment: Ah, sorry, my bad. It appears what I said requires you to change how you're applying the sort to the tables. I was referencing this: https://material.angular.io/components/sort/overview Perhaps that might help. There is also this demo: https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/demo-app/table/table-demo.ts