# Angular ViewChild custom sort selector

Tags: angular, sorting, angular-material2, viewchild

I'm learning about angular ViewChild currently, but I seem to be missing something when using ViewChild to select custom reference variables from the DOM.

In my template I have two tables:

```
<mat-table #eventTable [dataSource]="eventDataSource" matSort>
<mat-table #eventDateTable [dataSource]="dateEventDataSource" matSort>
```

I am attempting to target them with a sort for each:

```
@ViewChild('eventTable') eventTableSort: MatSort;
@ViewChild('eventDateTable') eventDateTableSort: MatSort;
```

Then I attempt to initiate them in `ngAfterViewInit()`:

```
this.eventDataSource.sort = this.eventTableSort;
this.dateEventDataSource.sort = this.eventDateTableSort;
```

The result is nothing happens on either table when I click the headers to sort each column. I'm sure there is something simple I am overlooking here but I can't see what it is. How can I make each of these tables sort independently of each other?

Comment: Are you sure you are dealing with `angularjs` and not `angular` and `angular-material` and `angular-material2` ? Your code looks like `angular` constructs (currently version 5.x)

Comment: @bhantol whoops I used the wrong tags, fixed now. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had been attempting to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47271379/angular-material-2-multiple-mat-table-with-matsort-within-the-same-component) question to derive and answer but it wasn't making sense to me. So I dove into a `debugger` and found an answer to my question.

When declaring a reference variable (`#eventTable` and `#eventDateTable`) you are creating a reference to the element/component/directive that you have declared it on. In my example I was creating a reference to each `<mat-table>` I had created. I was then attempting to assign these tables themselves to the `eventTableSort` and `eventDateTableSort` values. In `ngAfterViewInit()` I was essentially saying to set the sort for each dataset equal to the table it's stored in.

The correct way to go about targeting the `MatSort` for each table is to declare it when setting your reference variables. Rather than `#eventTable` which will create a reference for the whole table, `#eventTable="matSort"` will create a reference directly to that table's MatSort object. Then in your component you can use a `ViewChild` to target the `MatSort` itself.

Here are the same code I have written above now working correctly:

```
<mat-table #eventTable="matSort" [dataSource]="eventDataSource" matSort>
<mat-table #eventDateTable="matSort" [dataSource]="dateEventDataSource" matSort>

@ViewChild('eventTable') eventTableSort: MatSort;
@ViewChild('eventDateTable') eventDateTableSort: MatSort;

this.eventDataSource.sort = this.eventTableSort;
this.dateEventDataSource.sort = this.eventDateTableSort;
```