# Mat Sort on asynchronous in Mat Table with MatPaginator not working, datasource assigned asynchronously in template

Tags: angular, asynchronous, angular-material, datasource, mat-table

I am trying to add a matSort to this already working and existing MatTable. I've tried to implement what I found on this other thread here [mat-sort not working on mat-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48731798/mat-sort-not-working-on-mat-table), as it looks like describing the same issue, but can't manage to make it work. I believe one of the reasons might be that my dataSource is asynchronously calculated in the template rather than in the TS file I reckon. 
Just for clarity, I had previously changed the way it was retrieving the dataSource, I moved it to the TS file, but still the UI wasn't updating.

Here a simplified version of the code:

TEMPLATE:

```
 <table matSort mat-table [dataSource]="(searchMode === 'shift') ? shifts : (searchMode === 'booking') ? bookings">

 <ng-container matColumnDef="orgName">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef  mat-sort-header> Organisation </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.orgName}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="workerName">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef  mat-sort-header> Worker </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.workerName}} </td>
        </ng-container>

</table>
      <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20, 50, 100]" [pageSize]="20" [length]="total" (page)="onPageChange()" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
```

TS file:

```
import {MatTable, MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material/table';
import {MatPaginator} from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';

export class TsGenerationSearchTableComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges, AfterViewInit {

  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Shift>();
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: false}) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: false}) sort: MatSort;

  selectedWeekend: string;
  selectedWeekStart: string;


ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
}

 ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }


  onPageChange() {
    const data: GetShiftTimesheetData = {
      action: (this.searchMode === 'shift') ? 'PageGetShiftsForTsAction' : (this.searchMode === 'booking') ? 'PageGetBookingsForTsAction',
      weekStartDate: this.selectedWeekStart,
      weekEndDate: this.selectedWeekend,
      paginator: {
        pageSize: this.paginator.pageSize,
        pageIndex: this.paginator.pageIndex
      }
    };
    this.search.emit(data);
  }
```

The sort does absolutely nothing visible in the UI. I've tried to subscribe in `ngOnChanges` to see if it was at least seen, like this:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
if (this.dataSource && this.paginator && this.sort) {
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.sort.sortChange.subscribe(val => {
      console.log(val);
    });
    }
  }
```

and the log shows that it's at least reacting to the `sortChange`:

```
{active: "workerName", direction: "asc"}
```

and

```
{active: "workerName", direction: "desc"}
```

but nothing in the UI. I've tried doing `this.dataSource.sort = val;` in the subscription but throws the error `ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.`

Any help/tip is welcome. Thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 1):

You could try programmatically creating the table element and rendering it only once data is available.

**1)** Create a separate component & template for table using mat-table.

**2)** Import that component and inject ComponentFactoryResolver class into your TsGenerationSearchTableComponent class.

```
import { ComponentFactoryResolver } from '@angular/core';
import { MyCustomMatTableComponent } from 'your/path/to/component';


export class TsGenerationSearchTableComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }
    ....
```

**3)** Use a placeholder via directive in your template for your incoming table.  This placeholder will expose *ViewContainerRef* which is what you'll need there. ( Create then declare PlaceholderDirective in your app module. )

placeholder.directive.ts:

```
import { Directive, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appPlaceholder]'
 })
export class PlaceholderDirective {

  constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }

}
```

tsGenerationSearchTableComponent.html:

```
<!-- Add this where ever you want your table to be rendered -->
<ng-template appPlaceholder></ng-template>
```

**4)** Add ViewChild selector for placeholder in tsGenerationSearchTableComponent.ts:

```
  @ViewChild(PlaceholderDirective) yourMatTableComponent: PlaceholderDirective; // By passing in 
  a class to ViewChild, it will find the first instance of said class.
```

**5)** Subscribe to dataSource fetch... and use ComponentFactoryResolver to render your table only when data is successfully retrieved.

```
this.fetchData.subscribe((data) => {
   const customMatTableFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(MyCustomMatTableComponent); 
   const viewContainerRef = this.matTablePlaceHolder.viewContainerRef;

   hostViewContainerRef.clear(); // This will clear anything that was previously rendered in the ViewContainer.
   const componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(customMatTableFactory);
})
```

Comment: Hi man, thanks a lot for the time you took to answer my question. I did solve it over the weekend, but your solution will still be useful for someone else. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Oh nice.  I had a similar issue with MatSort before... so I'll book mark your solution as well. :)  Also, if you don't mind up voting my solution I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this issue in the following way. Basically the `dataSource` was being passed straight from the store, hence the sorting was not happening regardless of my efforts in the TS file.

So first of all I changed the datasource like this: 
`<table matSort mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">` and, in the TS file I created a method `initialiseDataSource()` to initialise it, which is called in the `ngOnInit()`.

```
  initialiseDataSource() {
    const dataSource = this.searchMode === 'timesheet' ? this.timesheets : this.shifts);
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Shift | Timesheet>(dataSource);
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    });
  }
```

It couldn't actually be simpler. Biggest takeaway from this issue is that the sorting needs to be applied to a local dataSource to happen, and in my case it wasn't.