# mat-sort and mat-paginator not working on Angular Material mat-table

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2, angular-material-table

I was trying to use the mat-sort and mat-paginator on my Material table which does not seem to work. The Table does get the data in the dataSource.data and it is also shown in the mat-table, but the dataSource.sort and dataSource.paginator properties stay *undefined*. I have tried to assign the values to both the properties in both ngOnInit() and ngAfterViewInit() as suggested in the other similar questions like the one here: [mat-sort not working on mat-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48731798/mat-sort-not-working-on-mat-table), but nothing seems to work. Below is the code for the same. The version of Angular Material is 8.2.3 and the version of Angular is 8.3.25. I'll be glad for any help. Thanks in advance :)

employees-list.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RestApiService } from '../shared/rest-api.service';
import { MatTableDataSource, MatSort, MatPaginator } from '@angular/material'; // Service used for Snackbar, Dialog,


@Component({
  selector: 'app-employees-list',
  templateUrl: './employees-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employees-list.component.scss']
})
export class EmployeesListComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  public Employee: any = [];
  public dataSource: any;
  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'name', 'email', 'phone', 'actions'];

  constructor(public restApi: RestApiService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadEmployees();
  }

  // Get employees list
  loadEmployees() {
    return this.restApi.getEmployees().subscribe((data: {}) => {
      console.log(data);
      this.Employee = data;
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.Employee);
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      console.log(this.dataSource);
    });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
  }

  // Delete employee
  deleteEmployee(id) {
    if (window.confirm('Are you sure, you want to delete?')) {
      this.restApi.deleteEmployee(id).subscribe(data => {
        this.loadEmployees();
      });
    }
  }

}
```

employees-list.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="Employee.length !== 0">

  <span class="mat-headline">Employee List</span>

  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8" >

    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> User ID </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.id}} </td>
    </ng-container>


    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
    </ng-container>


    <ng-container matColumnDef="email">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Email </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.email}} </td>
    </ng-container>


    <ng-container matColumnDef="phone">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Phone </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.phone}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Actions </th>   
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> 
        <button mat-raised-button routerLink="/employee-edit/{{element.id}}" color="primary"
        style="margin-right: 0.25rem;"><mat-icon>edit</mat-icon></button> 
        <button mat-raised-button (click)="deleteEmployee(element.id)" color="warn"><mat-icon>delete</mat-icon></button> 
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5,10,20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Before assigning `this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;` invoke `this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();`. Here are some issues and solutions related to sorting not working [Read Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46893164/mat-table-sorting-demo-not-working)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is when you render you component you have this

```
*ngIf="Employee.length !== 0
```

so right now you don't have anything in your view until your condition becomes true and in this time your

```
 @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;
 @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;
```

is trying to catch the sort and paginator from the view but your view doesn't have anything because your condition in this time isn't true so If you try to remove your condition everything will work

Comment: I had the same problem as the asker. Thank you very much for the answer! But what if I do need this null-check condition?

Comment: @NicoleNaumann not sure if this is still useful to you, but at least for future visitors: check out `[hidden]`

Answer (score 3):

**Use setters to solve the problem**

```
  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: false })
  set sort(v: MatSort) {
   this.dataSource.sort = v;
  }

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: false })
  set paginator(v: MatPaginator) {
    this.dataSource.paginator = v;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! Been searching for hours for a solution. For some reason, ngAfterViewInit isn't working for me and I still need lazy-loading. This works great.